# Use CSS to Print Page in Landscape Mode

Tags: css, printing

I am trying to print a page in landscape-mode.

I found the following CSS code:

```
 @page {
 size: landscape;
 }
```

This code is not having any affect on my page.
From what I understand, the `size` option is depracated.

Is there an alternative way to rotating a page so that it's printed in landscape mode?

(note: I want to avoid using `transform: rotate(90deg);` if possible.)

Thank you!

Shalva

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   @media print {
        @page {
            size: landscape;
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but I understood online that 'size: landscape;'
is deprecated. Are you aware of an alternative?